# Query data with timestamp since yesterday

Tags: php, date, time

Currently I check how many new members my website have received per day; like this:

```
$daystart = strtotime("00:00:00");
$newusers = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE createtime>'$daystart' OR createtime='$daystart'"));
```

the `createtime` row is `int(11)`, and the time is stored in an unix timestamp.

My question is, how can I make so the above query takes from yesterday? (How many new members the previous day)

I tried with `strotime('-1 day')` but that did not function well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Unix timestamps, you can use the timestamp for 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 for a day and get everything that's been added in between.

```
$starttime = date('U', strtotime('Yesterday 00:00:00'));
$endtime = date('U', strtotime('Yesterday 23:59:59'));
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE createtime >= $starttime AND createtime <= $endtime;";
```

You might also use the SQL BETWEEN-statement, but sometimes it doesn't retrieve all data.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use `DateTime`:

```
$yesterday = new DateTime("yesterday");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strtotime('yesterday');
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from users WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(createtime)) = DATE(DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL '-1' DAY))
```

Untested, but likely to work.

Comment: Thinking about this more, as convenient as it is to work with the datetime data type, efficiency still needs to be considered when using it.  It would be more efficient to get the unix timestamp for yesterday at 12 AM and today at 12 AM and select everything in between those than it would be to do 2 date conversions, so if you're doing this with thousands of rows across joins and such you may want to consider another way.  If you have a small query, this method should be fine.

Comment: You should edit that into your answer rather than leaving it as a comment.